# How to use cmake's try_run under windows on network drives

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm using CMake to build my project. The project uses some parts of the vxl (http://vxl.sourceforge.net) library. Since I don't need the full vxl lib, I build only the parts I need within my projcet by using cmake's ExternalProject. The Linux port of my project compiles without problems.

The Windows port also compiles fine, if I run everything locally (on C:) on my Windows box! My home dir is mounted as network drive. If I put the cmake build stuff to my home (lets say Z:\ProjectBuild), the vxl configuration (executed by ExternalProject) won't be correct.

The vxl cmake project carries out several tests (e.g. for data types) that use the cmake try_run() command. The created test exe in Z:\ProjectBuild\path\to\exe\ has a side-by-side configuration problem. Windows cannot resolve the path to debugging CRT dlls. If I do the same thing on C:, I don't run in any problems, however I want to have the build stuff in my home. The use of the Visual Studio command prompt didn't solve the problem.

I'm not sure, if it is a cmake problem (in terms of cmake configuration) or a Windows/Visual Studio problem (side-by-side configuration or path).

Any suggestions?

My machine:
Windows XP,
VS 2005 (SP1),
CMake 2.8.1

Thank you
 Tobias

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved. Using another mapped drive under Windows solves the problem. It seems to be sync problem with the Samba shares for my mapped home dir.

The created manifest for the little test application wasn't completely written and than VS embeds a empty manifest without any side-by-side configuration.